# Rails route /me should point to /account/:id of logged in user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a RESTful API in Ruby on Rails. Using the gem jsonapi-resources.

I would like to implement a route, like `/me`. It should always route to `/account/:id` where the `id` is the id of the currently logged in user.

So, `/account/:id/tasks` should be the same as `/me/tasks`.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this :

```
namespace :me do
  get '/', to: 'accounts#show'
  get '/tasks', to: 'tasks#index'
end
```

Then, in your controller, you retrieve the current user (with `current_user` if you are using Devise)

Comment: When I do it like that, `/me/tasks` will return ALL tasks, instead of MY tasks.
The `jsonapi-resources` gem generates routes for me, like this: 
`get "accounts/:account_id/tasks", to: "tasks#get_related_resources", relationship: 'tasks', source: 'accounts'`

I was hoping I could re-use those. But... it complains that the `account_id` parameter is missing.

Comment: I worked around this by adding a `before_action` to the base controller class. The action sets the `account_id` param to the currently logged in user. Now I can re-use the gem's autogenerated routes. Hooray!

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by writing to retrieve the current user. Glad it works.